# Select com condição

Tags: mysql, sql, sintaxe

Possuo a seguinte tabela de exemplo (tbl_Local) no MySQL:

```
ID| LOCAL|  COR
1 | A    |RED
2 | A    |RED
3 | B    |RED
4 | B    |BLACK
5 | B    |WHITE
6 | C    |RED
7 | D    |BLUE
8 | E    |BLUE
9 | E    |ORANGE
10| E    |YELLOW
11| E    |RED
12| F    |RED
13| G    |ORANGE
14| G    |BLUE
15| H    |ORANGE
```

Gostaria de criar um select que me retornasse **SOMENTE** os locais que possuem **EXCLUSIVAMENTE** a cor *RED*, ou seja, caso o `LOCAL` possua outra `COR` que não seja somente o **RED**  ele não deveria ser exibido.

Nessa tabela por exemplo o retorno deveria ser:

```
    LOCAL|  COR
    A    |RED
    C    |RED
    F    |RED
```

Tentei utilizar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
 Select tbl_Local.*, count(distinct(COR)) from tbl_Local where COR = 'RED' Group By LOCAL
```

Porém não funcionou, e estou sem ideias.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_Local WHERE COR = 'RED' GROUP BY LOCAL` não funciona?

Comment: Não funciona, porque nesse caso ele vai retornar o local 'E' que possui outras cores além de 'RED'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é o not exists:

```
Select distinct 
 t.Local,
 t.COR
from tbl_Local t 
Where t.COR = 'RED' 
and not exists (select 1 from tbl_Local x where x.LOCAL = t.LOCAL and x.COR != t.COR);
```

Aproveitei o SQLFiddle do @Barbetta: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82262e/10

> Seleciona todos onde a cor for vermelha e não existam o mesmo lugar com a cor diferente

Comment: Exatamente o que eu ia comentar agr

Comment: Rovvan obigado pela informação, porém, quando executo a instrução recebo o seguinte erro: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select 1 from tbl_Local x where x.Local = t.Local and x.COR != t.COR)' at line 5

Comment: tava errado o exists, já acertei

Comment: Exelente Rovann, era isso mesmo! Muito obrigado companheiro! Obrigado pelo esforço também Wees

Comment: disponha, =] boa tarde